# Why this inline method with deduced return type not defined yet?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

class C
{
    static auto func() { return std::string("hello"); }
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(func()), std::string>::value, "");
};
```

Neither GCC nor Clang accept this, saying that `func` is used before it is defined. Why?

Changing the deduced `auto` return type to `std::string` makes it work.

Comment: Inline function definitions are as if you wrote them right *after* the end of the class definition, so at the point of the `static_assert`, the function has not been defined yet.

Comment: @KerrekSB but changing the return type to explicit makes it compile fine

Comment: Sure, but the whole point of `auto` is to deduce the type from the definition...

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah, so IIUC you're saying with an explicit return type the function is *still* not defined within the class, but that's fine because it doesn't have to be defined for the `static_assert` to work?

Comment: When you make the return type explicit, the **declaration** of the function is sufficient to know the return type. When the return type is `auto` the compiler doesn't know at the point of the declaration what the return type is; it has to wait until the function is **defined**, which happens later.

Comment: @Danra: Yes. `decltype` is about (hold on tight) the declared type. But `auto` makes a declaration dependent on a definition.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks. Please, post it as an answer for others to learn :)

Comment: OK, done, I tried to embellish it a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `decltype` construction produces the declared type of an identifier or expression. When `func` is declared with a return type, then the type of the call expression `func()` is known and everything works as expected.

However, when `func` is declared with the return type placeholder `auto`, then the declaration of `func` *depends on its definition*, so the type of `func`, and hence of the expression `func()`, is not known until the function has been defined.

When you define a class member function inline in the class definition, this is as if the definition were to appear right after the end of the class definition (that is, the function bodies may make reference to names that are lexically declared *later* in the class definition). The consequence of this and the semantics of `auto` is that your function `auto func` is not actually fully *declared* until the end of the class definition, and thus the type of `func()` cannot be known until then.

Comment: "When you define a class member function inline in the class definition, this is as if the definition were to appear right after the end of the class definition" - Is there a good rationale for that?

Comment: @Danra: Common expectations of users to be able to refer to class members?

Comment: Wouldn't that still work if the inline functions were "appended" to the class definition? Which would in turn allow using their deduced return type.

Comment: @Danra: Sorry, I don't understand how what you said is different from what I said. It is indeed as if the definitions of the inline functions were "appended" to the class definition.

Comment: I thought you meant the functions are defined "past" the class definition, not appended to its end. In that case, what is the problem of using the deduced return type? Is it just a matter of the order within the class? (i.e. the type can't be used before it is "seen" by the compiler, which is later than when it needs it)

Comment: @Danra: Wait, what? The problem is the `static_assert`, which occurs *before* the end of the class definition and thus before the definition of the inline functions... There is no problem using one inline function from within another inline function, or any function for that matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136169/discussion-between-danra-and-kerrek-sb).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, a possible workaround is to defer the check to a static function and rely on the optimiser to remove all redundant code.

In a release build, this should be zero cost:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct C
{
    static auto func() {
        check_same();
        return std::string("hello");
    }

private:

    static void check_same()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(func()), std::string>::value, "");
    }
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << C::func() << '\n';
}
```