# Is it possible to initialize auto variable with auto class method?

Tags: c++, c++14

I met some problem regarding `auto` specifier using c++14.

I defined the class in header file as below,

```
class MiscFeature
{

public:
    MiscFeature();
    auto getData();
    auto setData(int);

private:
    int data;

};
```

Then calling the method in main file,

```
int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    MiscFeature * misc = new MiscFeature();

    auto val = misc->getData();
    cout<<val<<endl;
    val = misc->setData(6);
    cout<<val<<endl;
}
```

Then compiling with g++, I got the following errors:

> test.cpp:21:30: error: use of `auto MiscFeature::getData()` before deduction of `auto`
>
> ```
> auto val = misc->getData();
> ```

If I define the similar function in the main file, it's okay.

How could I fix such problem? Or is this a limitation?

Comment: Show us the code!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42329757

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why this inline method with deduced return type not defined yet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329757/why-this-inline-method-with-deduced-return-type-not-defined-yet)

Comment: @DeiDei added the code

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer for my question.
As class members are declared with auto specifier, when the method is invoked, the function should be defined and known.
However, in my above code example, main file only referred header files, so the function is still unknown. So compiler complains that.
Then I declared another inline function in header file and tested again.
Code as below,

```
class MiscFeature
{
public:
    MiscFeature();
    int getData();
    bool setData(int);
    auto testauto() { return 7;}
private:
    int data;
};
```

Then invoking the method testauto() in main file as below,

```
auto * misc = new MiscFeature();
auto val = misc->getData();
cout<<val<<endl;
auto ret = misc->setData(6);
cout<<ret<<endl;
auto val1 = misc->testauto();
cout<<val1<<endl;
```

Then compile and run it again, it worked.